# Split Rows into Columns on R

Tags: r, dplyr

my current data frame is

```
df <- data.frame(rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  Event = c("M", "D", "S", "D", "M", "D"),
                  duration = c(0.0000, 6.9600, 0.0245, 28.3000, 0.0513, 0.0832))
```

Would dplyr be able to split the rows into column so that the end result is

```
rep Start End duration
1     M   D   6.9600
1     D   S   0.0245
1     S   D   28.3000
1     D   M   0.0513 
1     M   D   0.0832
```

I need to essentially split the Event column into the Starting Event and then the Ending event type as well as the duration the system spent in the Starting Event. We always start at time 0.0000 so that will need to be ignored.

There are 50 replications within my data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is simply adding a `Start` and `End` column and shift `End` and `duration`  by one square with the `dplyr` `lead` function

```r
library(dplyr)

df%>%
  group_by(rep)%>%
  rename(Start=Event)%>%
  mutate(End=lead(Start),duration=lead(duration))%>%
  filter(!is.na(End))%>%
  relocate(End,.after="Start")
#>   rep Start End duration
#> 1   1     M   D   6.9600
#> 2   1     D   S   0.0245
#> 3   1     S   D  28.3000
#> 4   1     D   M   0.0513
#> 5   1     M   D   0.0832
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
   group_by(rep) %>%
   mutate(Start = lag(Event), End = Event, Event = NULL)%>%
   drop_na()

# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   rep [1]
    rep duration Start End  
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1   6.96   M     D    
2     1   0.0245 D     S    
3     1  28.3    S     D    
4     1   0.0513 D     M    
5     1   0.0832 M     D
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. is clean and neat!

Answer (score 1):

`cbind` the subsets.

```
cbind(df[-nrow(df), -3], df[-1, -1]) |> setNames(c("rep", "Start", "End", "duration"))
#     rep Start End duration
# 1   1     M     D   6.9600
# 2   1     D     S   0.0245
# 3   1     S     D  28.3000
# 4   1     D     M   0.0513
# 5   1     M     D   0.0832
```